# C++ Whitespace Delimiters Issue

Tags: c++, whitespace, delimiter

My program isn't displaying output as intended.

My text file: BNA Boston Red Stockings NA

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string team1, team2, team3, id;
string rank;
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("test.dat");
inFile >> id;
getline(inFile, team1, ' ');
getline(inFile, team2, ' ');
getline(inFile, team3, ' ');
inFile >> rank;

cout << endl << id << endl;
cout << team1 << ' ' << team2 << ' ' << team3 << endl << rank << endl << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

What is Output(which is incorrect):

```
BNA
Boston Red
Stockings
```

My inteded output:

```
BNA
Boston Red Stockings
NA
```

Any idea why my program isn't outputting as intended?
Thanks

Comment: Print each value after extraction. Once you do that and figure out `team1` is where the wheels fall off consider what `team1` stops consuming chars on, and what the *first* char in the input stream is after consuming `id` (spoiler: its the delimiter you're passing to `getline`).

Comment: Add a `inFile.ignore()` after `inFile >> id`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 inFile.ignore() worked, thanks!